# Naming conventions in matrix diagonalization $ D = S^{-1} \cdot A \cdot S $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, diagonalization, similar-matrices

The process of matrix diagonalzation is often summarized as

$$ D = S^{-1} \cdot A \cdot S $$

I understand that we often choose the first letter of the alphabet for the original matrix $A$ and $D$ for the diagonalized matrix.
But where does the name of the matrix $S$ come from?

Comment: In some texts it's $P$ instead of $S$

Comment: In some texts it's $U$ instead of $S$, In some texts it's $V$ instead of $S$,....

Comment: In my school books it depended on the context: S is mostly used for Symmetric Matrix, U for unitary ones, V for anti symmetric, P for other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think $S$ here stands for [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).